# how can i create header and footer view keep same as in each activites in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

i want to keep header and footer same as in all the activities just change the content between header and footer how it is possible.  below images display required how to do that stuff. please help thanks.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Use one activity with fragments as the content. Switching between activities will mean that the header and footer will also switch although they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the single layout for all the activites as below,

```
 // Header Activity..

   <RelativeLayout>
        // items in header activity
   </RelativeLayout>



 // Footer Activity..

   <RelativeLayout>
        // items in footer activity
   </RelativeLayout>


// In all activity

    <include android:id=”@+id/header”
     android:layout_width=”fill_parent”
     android:layout_height=”fill_parent”
     layout=”@layout/header_layout”/>

     <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/middle_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header_layout"
        >
         // middle layout
        </RelativeLayout>

    <include android:id=”@+id/footer”
     android:layout_width=”fill_parent”
     android:layout_height=”fill_parent”
     layout=”@layout/footer_layout”/>
```